# Virtualbox kali linux usb wifi adapter not working

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, usb

I get this error when I try to add USB wireless adapter to my running Kali Linux.

```
Failed to attach the USB device Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter to the virtual machine Kali-Linux-2016.2-vbox-i686_1.

USB device 'Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter' with UUID {cb3700a9-5075-4cf4-8ad0-84772145a1ae} is busy with a previous request. Please try again later.

Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
Component: HostUSBDeviceWrap
Interface: IHostUSBDevice {c19073dd-cc7b-431b-98b2-951fda8eab89}
Callee: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}'
```

I'm using a laptop, so I think there could be problem between my integrated wireless device and USB wireless adapter.

Comment: [This site is for Q&A about information security](http://security.stackexchange.com/tour), for technical problems about specific OS or device I strongly suggest to use the [Kali Linux Forums](https://forums.kali.org/)

Comment: What model is the USB wireless adapter?

Comment: You see that error only plugin the adapter? or after a command? in that case, what command?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but I found a solution.

Follow these steps:

1. Uninstall old versions of VirtualBox
2. Restart your PC
3. Download the latest versions of VirtualBox (`VirtualBox-5.1.28-117968-Win.exe`) and their extensions (`Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.28-117968..vbox-extpack`)
4. Create new folder in Program Files (example: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBoxNew`) and execute the installer of the new VirtualBox version. Make sure to install in your new directory.
5. Install the extensions
6. Done

Try the newly installed version of VirtualBox...